# add keys and values to a dictionary from multiple objects by for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Objects has been created by a website crawler. In this example, a *title* and the *image* file path is stored. The output is as following:

```
for article in fetcher.fetch():
    print(article.title + " | " + article.image)

Polarised modular conglomeration | ./img/1.jpg
Cross-group contextually-based middleware | ./img/2.jpg
De-engineered encompassing structure | ./img/3.jpg
Fully-configurable multi-tasking interface | ./img/4.jpg
Versatile eco-centric core | ./img/5.jpg
Optional maximized utilisation | ./img/6.jpg
Open-architected secondary product | ./img/7.jpg
```

The goal is to store *title* as key and *image* path as value in a dictionary

```
dict = {}

for dictionary in fetcher.fetch():
    dict = {dictionary.title: dictionary.image}

print(dict)
{'Open-architected secondary product': './img/7.jpg'}
```

Problem: Only the last item is stored in the dictionary. What is wrong with my code?

Thank you

Comment: you're creating a new `dict` every loop, instead of adding to an existing dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your existing loop (though @N Chauhan has a good dictionary comprehension):

```
for dictionary in fetcher.fetch():
    dict[dictionary.title] = dictionary.image
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you’re overwriting the `dict` each iteration. Use a dictionary comprehension instead:

```
article_info = {article.title: article.image
                for article in fetcher.fetch()}
```

Side note: always refrain from using *built-in* names as variables like your use of `dict` as a variable name. Just pick a more descriptive name - this will ultimately benefit in 2 ways:

- the default `dict` class is not shadowed.
- you have a better idea of what the variable is if you give it a good name instead of a vague one.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to an individual dictionary entry to add:
var[key]=value